# Remove the whole icon html after mouseleave

Tags: jquery

**CODE**

```
var inside = false;
var icon = '<i class="icn-close-white"></i>';
$('span').one('mouseenter', function(e){
    if(!inside){
        $(this).after(icon);
        inside = true;
    }
}).one('mouseleave', function(e){
    $(this).find('i').removeClass('icn-close-white');
    inside = false;
});
```

The images will be in some kind of gallery. So when the image is mouseover, the  black overlay will appear with close icon. When mouseleave, the close icon would disappear.

Tested with mouseover and mouseleave, the icon appears on mouseover, but not disappear on mouseleave. The icon stays stuck to the image.

Any pointer will be appreciated. thanks

**Update**

Tried the code as given by you, but one time, icon disappeared, and then again tried to mouseover again twice, icon didn't appear again. Not sure why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the icon is inserted after the `span` element, find the `next` icon element and then remove it instead of removing the class

```
$(this).next('i.icn-close-white').remove();
```

Complete

```
var inside = false;
var icon = '<i class="icn-close-white"></i>';
$('span').on('mouseenter', function (e) {
    if (!inside) {
        $(this).after(icon);
        inside = true;
    }
}).on('mouseleave', function (e) {
    $(this).next('i.icn-close-white').remove();
    inside = false;
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/66b3L/)

Comment: tried your method, but when mouseover / mousenter is done once, tried to mouseover/mouseenter again (twice), icon is no longer there.

Comment: @kittymeows because you used `one` instead of `on`

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems right. Try to add class which has nothing to display:

```
var inside = false;
var icon = '<i class="icn-close-white"></i>';
$('span').one('mouseenter', function(e){
    if(!inside){
        $(this).after(icon);
        inside = true;
    }
}).one('mouseleave', function(e){
    $(this).find('i').removeClass('icn-close-white').addClass('add here'); or $(this).find('i').removeClass('icn-close-white').remove();
    inside = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `removeClass` this will removes the class `icn-close-white` from the element

use `remove()` to remove the element

like @arun told you

```
$(this).next('i.icn-close-white').remove();
```

you have to try show/hide in this case

```
$(element).show(); // mouseover
```

and

```
$(element).hide(); // mouseout
```

Comment: tried that but it works only once after mouseleave, but when mouseover again, close icon won't be there anymore. I am not sure why